# Laravel Tailwind CSS Not displaying in browser

Tags: php, css, laravel, tailwind-css

I had a similar question previously. I'm still having problems so changed the question. I'll summarize suggested responses and why they did not work.

When I create a new project in laravel and add some tailwind css, the styles are not displaying in browser. I'm very new to laravel. I'm missing a step but don't know what.

I create new project with

`composer create-project laravel/laravel testcssproject`

I open the default blade at

`resources/views/welcome.blade.php`

Underneath this section in the default blade:

```
<p class="mt-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-sm leading-relaxed">Laracasts offers thousands of video tutorials on Laravel, PHP, and JavaScript development. Check them out, see for yourself, and massively level up your development skills in the process.</p>
```

I add this

```
<p class="text-8xl font-bold text-red-500">This should be large, bold, and red</p>
```

So I expect to see my new paragraph underneath the default paragraph that states "Laravel offers...". The paragraph should be large, bold, and red.

When I load the page in the browser, I see

[image]

As you can see, the paragraph is there but it doesn't have any styling.

FIXES I'VE TRIED

1. `php artisan view:clear` followed by restarting the server and a hard refresh. No difference.
2. `php artisan view:clear, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan routes:clear, php artisan config:clear`, followed by restarting the server and a hard refresh. No difference
3. `npm run dev` did nothing.
4. A helpful user asked if I was seeing font-bold class in the inspector for the element. This is what I see when I inspect the paragraph I created

[image]

I don't get it. I assume Tailwind is working because all the styling from the default welcome.blade.php is showing. Why is my paragraph appearing but not getting styled?

Thanks for your help,
G

EDIT:

After install breeze using all commands suggested in answer, I now see login and register options but paragraph is still not styled

[image]

EDIT 2:

Here is my tailwind config file. Is something missing?

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

Comment: can you check in your tailwind config file, if there is a 'mode' set to 'jit'?

Comment: @NikolaKirincic I don't think so, i edited question to add my tailwind config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vite on your blade layout page

Answer (score 1):

to make it easier for you:

1. `composer create-project laravel/laravel testcssproject`
2. `cd testcssproject`
3. `composer require laravel/breeze --dev`
4. `php artisan breeze:install`
5. `php artisan migrate`
6. `npm install`
7. `npm run build`
8. `php artisan serve`
9. read this docs https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze

Comment: Thank you. I tried all of this. Now on my main page i see the "Log In" and "Register" options at the top right of the page. However the paragraph I created is still not styled. See the edit in my question for the updated image

Comment: you just need to add this code in the head tag `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])`

Comment: That did it thank you! What does that do, and how come I had to add it? The default structure of the page was styled, so how come the default content was styled but style I added was not updating?

Comment: you can read this article https://laravel-news.com/laravel-blade-hot-refresh-with-vite